# Attendance reader with iBeacon/eddystone and raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibeacon, bluez, beacon, eddystone

I'm a bit confused. I explain to you my project, I would like to make a "reader" by using beacon technology (ibeacon for apple, eddystone for android) using a raspberry pi 3. The smatphone application sends an acknowledgment code when passing the person. The raspberry marks and updates an online database. I wanted to ask, first of all can this be done? My problem is to realize the beacon transmission, then for the app and the database I have no problems. I tried using bluez but I can not detect the phone. Is there any online tutorial that could help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use the phone to emit a beacon transmission and then use the Raspberry Pi 3 to detect the beacon, then yes, this is possible.  I put together a tutorial on [how to use the Android Things to detect beacons](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/06/18/detecting-beacons-with-android-things) on the Raspberry Pi 3.

The problem with using BlueZ for beacon detection is that it is simply not stable on the Raspberry Pi, and will freeze up and stop detecting requiring a reboot.

Comment: Yes, because I would basically like to have a presence reader for my school. Students in the morning enter the entrance where there are raspberry and mark all past people present. Can this be done?

Comment: It can be done.  But because you need an app to be in the foreground on iOS to send a beacon transmission, you have to decide if this is practical.  Will students bring your app to the foreground to be counted?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, the app must do it for android too. Do you know a tutorial or something from which I can get started? My difficulty is to set the most raspberry